# Pandas replace with dict issue

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am making replace via dict on large series (3M records approx). Dict size is ~11k like this:

```
data['TOBE'] = data['ASIS'].replace(zdict)
```

It takes a while and then i obtain an error of type mismatch:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'
```

I checked the dict:

```
set([str(type(key)) for key in zdict.keys()])
```

gives:

```
{"<class 'str'>"}
```

Then checked the Series data:

```
set([str(type(val)) for val in data['ASIS']])
```

gives:

```
{"<class 'str'>"}
```

The i tried to replace chunks, eg:

```
data['ASIS'][:1500000].replace(zdict)
data['ASIS'][1500000:].replace(zdict)
```

and got no error...

So now i cant understand why i get this strange error on the whole scope, but dont get it on chunks, which cover all scope.

Answer (score 1):

I see that what you are replacing with is a zdict data. If this represents [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zdict) Python framework, then would you consider trying to replace with a dummy data in string format instead with the zdict data. If this is possible then there might be a bug with the framework itself for large amount of data.

Comment: Thank you! Didnt know about zdict package, but this is my varaible name. 
Coincidence :(

Comment: No problem. I wasn't sure. Have you tried slicing it this way: `[:]` or slicing with increasing value like 1 500 000 then 2 000 000 then 2 500 000 to check when will it break?

Comment: Not yet, but i will definately try bigger slices

Answer (score 0):

So my only hypotesis is that its an insufficient memory issue which is not processed by exception.

I am thinking of it because while replacing i get ~98% RAM usage. I have only 8 GB.

The chunk approach seems to work.